# Do primes of the form $n^2+1$, proportional to $p_n^2$, converge?

Tags: prime-numbers, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

An open and famously difficult problem is to (dis)prove the infinitude of primes of the form $n^2+1$. My question is related to these primes:

> Suppose there are infinitely many primes of the form $n^2+1$. Let $p_k$ denote the $k$-th prime and $s_k$ the $k$-th prime of the form $n^2+1$. My question is: does
> $$\lim_{k \to \infty} s_k/p_k^2$$
> Exist, and if so, what does it converge to?

I conjecture that it does, though I had an unusual amount of trouble finding information on the asymptotics for primes of the form $n^2+1$. I suspect [a work of Bateman and Horn](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1962-16-079/S0025-5718-1962-0148632-7/S0025-5718-1962-0148632-7.pdf) to be useful here, but it's a little high-level for me.

I computed the first ~two million or so primes of the form $n^2+1$ and plotted $s_k/p_k^2$, for your leisure.

[image]

Comment: For clarity's sake, I presume that the "$n$" in $n^2+1$ is not the same "$n$" in $p_n$ and neither are the same "$n$" in $s_n$. If so, an edit might be useful. For example, which "$n$" is being plotted on the horizontal axis of your graph?

Comment: @KeithBackman You are correct, I have editted accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a conjectured asymptotic formula (indeed from the Bateman–Horn conjecture) for the number of positive integers $k\le x$ for which $k^2+1$ is prime, of the form $\sim Cx/(\log x)$ for a particular positive constant $C$. This implies that the $n$th such integer $k$ has size asymptotically equal to $\sim \frac1C n(\log n)$, and thus that the $n$th such prime $k^2+1$ has size asymptotically equal to $\sim \frac1{C^2} n^2(\log n)^2$. Since $p_n \sim n\log n$ by the prime number theorem, we see that $s_n/p_n^2$ conjecturally tends to the constant $\frac1{C^2}$.

I can't recover it now, but the constant $C$ can be estimated explicitly, so that should give a numerical value for the constant $\frac1{C^2}$ that could be checked against your numerical explorations.

Comment: Your $C$ is the constant called $C_1/2$ here:  http://yves.gallot.pagesperso-orange.fr/primes/stat.html.  So $1/C^2 \approx 2.12244738143$.  (I think the $\sim 5\%$ discrepancy with the experimental data is caused by the difference between $x/\log x$ and $\mathrm{Li}(x)$.)

Comment: Thank you @RaviFernando !